# new line in xsl but the code is not working

Tags: xslt

In the search result display xsl I added following code but none of them giving me new line.

```
<xsl:text> &amp;#10; </xsl:text>

<xsl:text> &#10; </xsl:text>

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" >&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: What kind of output do you create (HTML, XML, plain text)? And how do you look at the output? The middle one (`<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>`) should output a linefeed character. Whether a browser renders a linefeed in an HTML document however as a new line depends on the element it is in and the CSS applied. For instance `<pre>Line 1.&#10;Line 2.</pre>` would usually be rendered as two lines, `<p>Line 1.&#10;Line 2.</p>` not.

Comment: Martin, you are right, it's probably driven by the CSS which SharePoint heavly relies on. SharePoint pages are based on .net (aspx) so out put to html

Answer (score 0):

If you output HTML with your XSLT and want a line break then use a `br` element e.g. `<br/>`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.2.1. The character `&#10;` is simply treated as white space and does not result in line break unless used inside a `pre` element or other element with the CSS defining `white-space: pre`.

Comment: <br> or </br> did not compile.

Comment: Well my suggestion is `<br/>` and not a single `<br>` nor a single `</br>`. If you want to write it out then instead of `<br/>` you can also use `<br></br>` in XML (and XSLT is XML).